# PHP if _POST is equal do this if not equal do this getting double value

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, variables

I need to filter how to save results in MySQL according to the form values but the echo test show me 2 results

Here is the select form

```
<select name="documento" id="documento">
<option value="boleta">boleta</option>
<option value="comprobante" selected>comprobante</option>
<option value="factura">factura</option>
</select>
```

Here is the test before I save to MySQL, getting the values from the select form

```
$mismofolio=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['mismofolio']);
$cliente = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['cliente']);
$documento=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['documento']);

if (empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'boleta') {
    echo "boleta folio nuevo";
}
if (!empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'boleta') {
    echo "boleta con el mismo folio $mismofolio";
}
if (empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'comprobante') {
    echo "comprobante folio nuevo";
}
if (!empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'comprobante') {
    echo "comprobante con el mismo folio $mismofolio";
}
if (empty($mismofolio) || empty($cliente) && $documento == 'factura') {
    echo "factura folio nuevo";
}
if (!empty($mismofolio) || !empty($cliente) && $documento == 'factura') {
    echo "factura mismo folio $mismofolio";
}
```

I just have to echo 1 value but the result I get is:

```
Selecting: documento=boleta
```

Echo:

```
BOLETA FOLIO NUEVOFACTURA FOLIO NUEVO
```

As you can see the php code is taking 2 if and not 1, this is bad because I could save 2 times in MySQL

Both $mismofilio and $cliente are empty in the test so I have to only echo

```
{echo "boleta folio nuevo";}
```

But I cannot understand why it is displaying more...

Comment: Your logic seems to be a little wrong. If `empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'boleta'` is true, then `empty($mismofolio)` is true and `empty($mismofolio) || ...` is true, too

Comment: What really surprises me is that your code has lowercase strings, yet your output is in upper case....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have brackets surrounding your OR statements (#5 and #6):

```
    if (empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'boleta')
{echo "boleta folio nuevo";}
    if (!empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'boleta')
{echo "boleta con el mismo folio $mismofolio";}
    if (empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'comprobante')
{echo "comprobante folio nuevo";}
    if (!empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'comprobante')
{echo "comprobante con el mismo folio $mismofolio";}
    if ((empty($mismofolio) || empty($cliente)) && $documento == 'factura')
{echo "factura folio nuevo";}
    if ((!empty($mismofolio) || !empty($cliente)) && $documento == 'factura')
{echo "factura mismo folio $mismofolio";}
```

Without the brackets, empty($mismofolio) by itself is equating to true, which is why "factura folio nuevo" is being printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is being evaluated as:

```
if (empty($mismofolio) || (empty($cliente) && $documento == 'factura'))
```

hence the second output. Perhaps you meant this instead?

```
if ((empty($mismofolio) || empty($cliente)) && $documento == 'factura')
```

Comment: working fine!!! Just a question: I fixed this if ((empty($mismofolio) || empty($cliente)) && $documento == 'factura') - but the follow is correct or I must do changes too ? if (empty($mismofolio) && $documento == 'boleta'){echo "boleta folio nuevo";} ???